# scrapy.core.engine DEBUG: Crawled (403) https://publicholidays.com/us/school-holidays/

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, http-status-code-403

```
import scrapy

class UsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'us_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://publicholidays.com/us/school-holidays/']

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response)
        print(response.request.headers)
        print("\n")

        yield {
            "hi": "hello"
        }
```

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPL8i.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZHmB.png)

Comment: Somehow you've forgotten to write your question

Answer (score 0):

The response means the remote server refuses your request. The reason for this might be security concerns of the remote.

Try to send the required request headers like a real user. You can check them by using the DevTools on your browser.

1. Open your browser's **dev tools**.
2. Click the **Network** tab.
3. Open the web page that you want to crawl.
4. Click on the page's result. Its type will be **document**.
5. Scroll down till you see the **Request Headers** section.
6. Send the same request headers.

Comment: Not happening, & Send a screenshot.